# windows 10 does not go to sleep

Tags: windows, sleep, hybrid-sleep

I have always been able to put my pc to sleep and so I can continue where I left. But after recent updates from Microsoft, I am unable to put my pc to sleep. I press Sleep and it goes to sleep but actually shuts down instead because it is fresh with a move the mouse, like waking my pc up from shutdown instead.

I have tried everything: Uninstalled recent update KB4537572 updated all drivers checked by bios activated hibernate but same problem

**Tried all the followings:**
 - updated Intel Management Engine Interface (v. 11.7.0.1045)
 - looked at bios and done the approp. changes.
 - updated all my drivers

nothing helps :-(

```
powercfg /A
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S3)
    Hibernate
    Hybrid Sleep
    Fast Startup

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
    Standby (S1)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
```

The funny thing is that my pc goes to sleep in a while. Meaning if I wake up my pc within fews mins then it return to previous state (Sleep mode) but if I keep my pc sleeping all night, then it kinda shutsdown from sleep because when I start pc then it is fresh again.

Please any advice? anybody managed to slove similar problems?

Comment: Try updating BIOS and your power driver - both.

Answer (score 0):

If you put it to sleep at night, and the next day it has rebooted, maybe something's happening at night that's triggering this.

You can check the Windows Event Viewer to look for events related to the reboot. 
Event 6008 indicates an "unexpected shutdown" which could be due to a crash, power outage, etc. Event 6009 appears when the computer starts up. EventEvent 1074 indicates a system-initiated shutdown.

To search your event viewer for specific events, you can use the filter feature. Open the Event Viewer and navigate to Windows Logs-System. This is where event related to rebooting will appear. On the right, click Filter Current Log. Then enter the desired IDs in the box labeled Includes/Excludes Event IDs. Enter all IDs you want, separated by commas. This will show only those IDs in the log, making it easy to see when they occurred.

Once you know when and why the reboot is happening then you may be able to track down the cause. Look at the time, and compare it to the times of any scheduled tasks on your system, for example.

I once had a user with a computer that rebooted every day, for no apparent reason. It turned out to be a problem with Windows updates. An update was attempted that forced a reboot, but the update failed to apply. 
The computer kept retrying the update and rebooting, so it was rebooting every day.

In that particular case it ended up being due to a problem with the Microsoft supplied drivers, and reinstalling the OEM drivers resolved the problem.

If you find an error saying that your computer's previous system shutdown was unexpected, that usually means either that your system lost power, or that it rebooted due to a Stop error, aka a "blue screen of death" (BSOD.)

BSODs are normally caused by either defective system hardware or bad/wrong device drivers. Device drivers are probably the more common cause, but hardware problems are often easier to identify so I usually start by checking for those.

One option is to configure your computer not to automatically reboot after a BSOD, which is done in your Windows System properties/Advanced tab, under Startup and Recovery. Uncheck the option to restart after a crash. This will cause your computer to stay on the crash screen, so you can see exactly what the error is. [More info...](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/69012-enable-disable-bsod-automatic-restart-windows-10-a.html)

Normally when Windows crashes with a BSOD, it captures some information in a special log which can be reviewed by developers. 
An easy way to look at these logs is to run a utility that reads and displays info from the logs. One free tool for this is available here: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

To check for a possible hardware problem, you'll want to run whatever hardware diagnostics your system came with. This will vary from one computer to another, but is often found as an option in the F12 startup menu. Consult your computer's documentation or tech support for details.

If you can't find any evidence of system crashes, then you are more likely looking at a power or hardware problem. A local power outage, surge, or drop that happens every night could cause this. A UPS with a failed battery is a common cause of this.

Other possible hardware causes can be an overheating CPU or GPU, power supply defects, etc.

Comment: Also look in your power settings if resume triggers are enabled, and disable them. From what you describe, your wait-til-sleep timeout is set too low, and after a while, it goes to sleep anyway.

Comment: I have looked at Events and see the following:
The start type of the Background Intelligent Transfer Service service was changed from demand start to auto start.
event id: 7040 (an update maybe)
but when I open my windows update, cannot see any recent updates there.

I have now disabled windows update for 5 days to see what happens!

Comment: It didn't really help. 
I turned my pc off at 04:57 and on again 15:25 and according to events nothing happened in between. I tried to put my pc to sleep for 30 mins and woke the pc again & pc kept sleep mode
Here is the logs:
`time 04:56: The system time has changed to ‎2020‎-‎03‎-‎29T02:56:58.239925700Z from ‎2020‎-‎03‎-‎29T02:56:58.239106600Z.

Change Reason: An application or system component changed the time.
Process: '\Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\svchost.exe' (PID 23796).`

`time 15:25: The operating system started at system time ‎2020‎-‎03‎-‎29T13:25:13.500000000Z..`

Comment: There are no events when the computer is off. The idea is to capture the events that happen overnight while the computer is on, so you can see what's happening without having to actually sit there and watch it for hours.

Comment: To search your event viewer for specific events, you can use the filter feature. Open the Event Viewer and navigate to Windows Logs-System. This is where event related to rebooting will appear. On the right, click Filter Current Log. Then enter the desired IDs in the box labeled Includes/Excludes Event IDs. Enter all IDs you want, separated by commas. This will show only those IDs in the log, making it easy to see when they occurred.

Comment: thx. found many of The previous system shutdown at 4:13:18 AM on ‎3/‎27/‎2020 was unexpected. Every day actually. How to find out what goes wrong?

Comment: I've added more info to my answer regarding possible troubleshooting steps.